# QGIS geologic SVG plotting problem

Tags: qgis

I'm plotting various structural geologic SVG symbols and am wondering how to have only a few of the symbols per line - ie., when I use an anticline symbol, I get a repetition of the symbol and when I change the size, I see still many of the same symbol, only larger. What sizing constraint am I missing?

Comment: maybe help us with an indication of the settings u're using ?

Comment: Are you using a marker line style with SVG marker?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the svg marker for the line style.

Answer (score 1):

Marker size does not affect how far apart the markers are. Marker spacing is controlled by the "marker placement" settings. The default setting is `with interval - 3.000000 Millimeter`.

[image]

Try using map units instead of millimeters. This will place your markers a fixed distance apart **in map units**. If you set your markers to be 500 map units apart, and your map units are meters, they will always be 500 meters apart. When you zoom in, they will appear further apart.

Comment: Yep - I was only looking at the parameters for the svg, not the marker placement, so thanks much! Any ideas on how to have a solid/dotted line plot with svg marker triangles for a thrust fault?

Comment: add another symbol level by clicking the green plus sign